# Is this expression informal?

Tags: politeness, formal-language

My boss asked me the send him some documents, I immediately attached the documents and  send him an email with the following body:

```
 Dear Thomas,


 I hope all is well with you. Thank you very much for your 
 message. Here it is.

 Best, 
 Linkho
```

My question:

Was it impolite to say him "here it is" ? Was it too informal?

How I could answered him politely? ( Politely and formally)

Comment: If he asked you, and you *immediately* sent the email, your initial greeting *(**I hope all is well with you**)* just sounds ridiculous. If he had any problems that he'd consider sharing with his employees, he'd have already told you. But you don't really need any "covering letter", since he's already *expecting* those documents anyway. Just ***As requested...*** is more than enough.

Comment: The fact that you are calling him Thomas suggests that it does not need to be overly formal, just polite and to the point. "Thomas, here are the documents you requested. Best, Linkho." That is not too familiar or intrusive, and not too abrupt.

Comment: @Weather Vane thanks, this means "here it is" is not formally or politely? I'm afraid it wasn't polite, I'm pretty new employee!

Comment: Thomas asked you for plural documents. To reply with just "here it is" is ungrammatical and rather abrupt.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to say "Attached are the documents you requested." It's more about clarity than formality. In a business environment it is generally more polite to be accurate and clear. In the message you sent, Thomas would need the context of his previous request (or to open what you sent him) to understand what it is you sent.